# I get this error when I try to enter a huge text and I dont know how to fix it

Tags: php

I get this error when I try to enter huge text and I dont know how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72054558/edit) your question to include the code and error message as text instead.

Comment: Your code is also _wide open_ to [SQL injection attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection). You should read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to learn how to safely add user data to your queries using prepared statements with placeholders. That will also fix the error you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't post error messages as screenshots.

The error comes from the apostrophe in "I've" which is closing out the single quote that your value is wrapped in. This error can be fixed by learning how to do prepared statements instead of concatenating your values in to the SQL statement, which can lead to [SQL Injection attacks](https://xkcd.com/327/).